# Django testing - Taking the initial values and feeding them back

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a basic model which references both ForeignKeys and ManyToMany objects.  In "edit" testing where you are taking the id of a view and making changes to it I ran into a problem and I'm curious if anyone else figured out a cleaner workaround. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235883/django-testing-test-the-initial-value-of-a-form-field) post which started me down the right path

```
    client = Client()
    response = client.get(reverse("floorplan_update", kwargs={'pk': floorplan.id}))

    data = response.context['form'].initial

    # Ideally you should be able to do this..
    response = client.post(reverse("floorplan_update", kwargs={'pk': floorplan.id}),
                           data=data, follow=True)
```

But you can't do this.  In cases where you have FK's or M2M's you need to first do this ugliness...

```
    client = Client()
    response = client.get(reverse("floorplan_update", kwargs={'pk': floorplan.id}))

    data = response.context['form'].initial

    # Ugliness ensues..
    data['document'] = open(__file__)
    data['company']= data['company'].id
    data['target']= data['target'].id

    # Only now can you post..

    response = client.post(reverse("floorplan_update", kwargs={'pk': floorplan.id}),
                           data=data, follow=True)
```

Has anyone else ran into this or is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but you can try this instead:

```
data = response.context['form'].instance.__dict__
```

Comment: That certainly get's you most of the way there.  Nice.